# How do I Import a .shp file into PGSQL via terminal?

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, import

I am stuck trying to import a .shp file into my pgsql database. I have been trying for the longest to import this one .shp file into pgsql. Below is my import statement.

```
       /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -h xxx.xx.xxx.xx -d areaft -U Mc shp2pgsql -s 4326 -W "latin1" travel.shp
```

The error messages I receive are:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "shp2pgsql" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "4326" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "latin1" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "travel.shp" ignored
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have combined two command which is not possible without linux pipes and the order is wrong.
First create the sql script from the shape file and then feed it to psql:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 -W "latin1" travel.shp > temp.sql
psql -h xxx.xx.xxx.xx -d areaft -U Mc -f temp.sql
```

or in a simple command:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 -W "latin1" travel.shp | psql -h xxx.xx.xxx.xx -d areaft -U Mc
```

Comment: Hey Zoltan, Thanks for your response. I tried running your command and i got `BASH shp2pgsql: command not found` Any idea why?

Comment: Note: I am trying to import the .shp file to my database on a remote server.

Comment: the shp2pgsql is not installed on your machine or on the remote machine (depending which machine you open your shell). I suppose on the remote machine you have postgresql and postgis installed, than you have shp2pgsql on the remote machine. Upload your shape file to the remote machine, open a remote shell (ssh) and type the commands.